# How to compare a value against a column value containing csv in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.2

I have a table called `device_info` that looks like below (only a sample provided)

| device_ip | cpu | memory |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100.33.1.0 | 10.0 | 29.33 |
| 110.35.58.2 | 3.0, 2.0 | 20.47 |
| 220.17.58.3 | 4.0, 3.0 | 23.17 |
| 30.13.18.8 | -1 | 26.47 |
| 70.65.18.10 | -1 | 20.47 |
| 10.25.98.11 | 5.0, 7.0 | 19.88 |
| 12.15.38.10 | 7.0 | 22.45 |

Now I need to compare a number say **3** against the `cpu` column values and get the rows that are greater than that. Since the `cpu` column values are stored as a csv, I am not sure how to do the comparison.

I found there is a concept called `string_to_array` in Postgres which converts csv to array and accordingly tried the below query that didn't work out

```
select device_ip, cpu, memory 
from device_info 
where 3 > any(string_to_array(cpu, ',')::float[]);
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Expected output**

| device_ip | cpu | memory |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100.33.1.0 | 10.0 | 29.33 |
| 220.17.58.3 | 4.0, 3.0 | 23.17 |
| 10.25.98.11 | 5.0, 7.0 | 19.88 |
| 12.15.38.10 | 7.0 | 22.45 |

Comment: it  is never a good idea to store mutiple values as csv in one column. You should read about normalization

Comment: Can you share the expected output table of your query?

Comment: @lemon I have added expected output.

Comment: @Jens I agree. But the table is designed by somebody else and I just need to get some numbers out. But I will definitely pass on the advice to that guy. Thanks.

Comment: Switch `>` to `<`. It reads the other way around as written.

Comment: @Isolated this is it! Now I know where its going wrong. Great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement as-is is saying "3 is greater than my array value". What I think you want is "3 is less than my array value".

Switch > to <.

```
select device_ip, cpu 
from device_info 
where 3 < any(string_to_array(cpu, ',')::float[]);
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9hs28z4k26HCnNgGY89Be7/0)

Comment: thanks! `<` and `>` is where I screwed up. Great work!